# PeerJS не работает loadedmetadata

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, peerjs

Когда я устанавливаю соединение через iPhone + MacOS, все работает. Но когда iPhone + Window/Android - событие **loadedmetadata** не срабатывает.

HTML тег

```
<video id='other-video' playsinline autoplay></video>
```

JavaScript код

```
const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play();
    });
};
```